# Why does one method of adding all the elements of an array fail when similar methods succeed

Tags: arrays, c, casting, addition

I have an array of doubles. To simplify the example, I use an array of length 3.  I want to add all 3 elements of the array. I do it in 3 ways.
Here's the program to demonstrate.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  double   a[3] =  {1.,3.,5.};

  double sum1 = a[0]+a[1]+a[2];

  int i=0;
  double sum2 = (double)a[i]+(double)a[i+1]+(double)a[i+2];

  double sum3 = a[i]+a[i+i]+a[i+2];

  printf("sum1=%f sum2=%f sum3=%f \n",sum1, sum2, sum3);
}
```

When you run it, you get

sum1=9.000000 sum2=9.000000 sum3=7.000000

Why does sum3 fail, especially when it should be equivalent to sum1? And why do I have to cast the individual elements of the array to double when the array itself is an array of doubles?

Comment: There is a typo a[i+i] in this expression a[i]+a[i+i]+a[i+2];

Comment: i+i is still zero.

Comment: What is your assignment or exercise? In `(double)a[i]` (for example) the explicit conversion to `double` is not needed, it just adds noise to the code.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thanks. I spent 2 hours on a much larger version of this, and I couldn't spot the typo.  Change i+i to i+1 and everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Line :

```
double sum3 = a[i]+a[i+i]+a[i+2];
```

`a[i+i]` should be `a[i+1]`.